# Unix file permissions - 3777 vs 2775

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems

People say unix file permissions 3777 is better than 2777, I understand this part. But is it right to say 3775 is better than 2775 as well?

Comment: I  would have a hard time coming up with a use case for any file being `*777` and any directory with `777` being something other than `1777`. For files, there will be no difference between `3775` and `2775` - the sticky bit isn't used on files any more. For directories, the difference will depend on your use case for non-owners deleting files out of the directory. Can't say which is "better" without knowing your requirements.

Comment: Oh I did not know that sticky bit is not used on files.

Comment: What I said is true for Linux and a few other OSes. Check out the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) for its use on other UNIX-like operating systems.